# Changing the class of select 'li' in a 4x3 li grid

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a 12-month-'li'-grid is being generated in each 'td' of the 'key months' row of my table created as follows:

```
var MonthArr = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
      var Monthlist = '<ul class="wrapper"><li class="boxFalse cross">' + MonthArr.join('</li><li class="boxFalse cross">') + '</li></ul>';
```

However, the 'change class' that I'm trying to get for the select months through the following code isn't working:

```
jQuery("li", Monthlist).each (function(){
          if (jQuery(this).text() == jQuery(SelectedMonthArrEach).text()) {
            jQuery(this).removeClass().addClass('boxTrue').addClass('tick');
          }  
        });
```

Following is the consolidated, relevant updated jquery code:

```
jQuery('.divResult table tbody tr td').each(function ($) {
      var MonthArr = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
      var Monthlist = '<ul class="wrapper"><li class="boxFalse cross">' + MonthArr.join('</li><li class="boxFalse cross">') + '</li></ul>';

      if (jQuery(this).text() == 'Key months') jQuery(this).nextAll("td").each(function ($) {     

        var SelectedMonthArr = jQuery(this).text().split(',');
        for (i=0; i<SelectedMonthArr.length; i++){
          var SelectedMonthArrEach = SelectedMonthArr[i];
          console.log(SelectedMonthArrEach);
        }

        jQuery("li", Monthlist).each (function(){
          if (jQuery(this).text() == jQuery(SelectedMonthArrEach).text()) {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('boxFalse cross').addClass('boxTrue').addClass('tick');
          }  
        });
        console.log(Monthlist);
        jQuery(this).empty().append(Monthlist);

    });
  });
```

The working jsfiddle for the code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/mithunu/hv8w6fbq/1/

Please do help me with where I'm going wrong!! :/

Answer (score 0):

```js
//You need to provide class names in jquery removeClass function

setTimeout(()=>{

jQuery("li.boxFalse").each (function(){
                          jQuery(this).removeClass("boxFalse cross").addClass('boxTrue').addClass('tick'); 
 });

},2000);
```

```css
.boxFalse{
  color:red !important;
}

.boxTrue{
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="wrapper"><li class="boxFalse cross">sdfds</li></ul>
```

Comment: Hi!! Thanks @Rahi! I tried your solution in my code, but it isn't working. I believe the problem in my code is that this part isn't being called upon. ````jQuery("li", Monthlist).each (function(){
          if (jQuery(this).text() == jQuery(SelectedMonthArrEach).text()) {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('boxFalse cross').addClass('boxTrue').addClass('tick');
          }```` . I thing I need to create a new function with a different name and then call it out, but not sure how.